# Remove invlaid character from email subject

Tags: vba, outlook

I have the following code

```
Sub RemoveInvalidChar(myMail As MailItem)


If myMail.Subject <> vbNullString Then
        strname = myMail.Subject
   Else

End If
strname = Replace(strname, "&", "and")

End Sub
```

Basically I want to replace the & char with the word and using a rule.  Doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub RemoveInvalidChar(myMail As MailItem)


If myMail.Subject <> vbNullString Then
        'set the actual subject to a new subject

        myMail.Subject= Replace(myMail.Subject, "&", "and")
        'get in the habit of saving email when you change it via vba
        'as there will be a lot of cases where you get burned for this
        myMail.Save
End If

End Sub
```

If this doesn't work, add a breakpoint and ensure you are actually calling the macro appropriately via the rule.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't set the myMail.Subject to your new string. Add the line below:

```
myMail.Subject = strname
```

But make sure you are sending `myMail` ByRef.

Comment: doesn't seem to do anything,

Comment: Are you sending the myMail object ByRef:
`Sub RemoveInvalidChar(ByRef myMail As MailItem)`

Comment: yes, this is what I have `Sub RemoveInvalidChar(ByRef myMail As MailItem)


If myMail.Subject <> vbNullString Then
        strname = myMail.Subject
   Else
     
End If
myMail.Subject = strname
strname = Replace(strname, "&", "and")
    
End Sub`

Answer (score 0):

enderland - I managed to get to the answer yesterday but couldn't post results.

I was missing the mymail.save

Anyway my code is below and it works.  The Ltrim just removes any preceding spaces from the front of the subject line.

```
Sub RemoveInvalidChar(myMail As MailItem)

    Dim strname As String
    Dim sreplace As String

    sreplace = "and"
    strname = LTrim(myMail.Subject)

    strname = Replace(strname, "&", sreplace)
    myMail.Subject = strname
    myMail.Save

End Sub
```

Comment: Like I said, `.Save` is a very frustrating and fairly common problem in doing things like this with Outlook...